# Найти номер строки заданной целочисленной матрицы, в которой находится самая длинная серия. Python3

Tags: python, матрицы

Задача такая: Найти номер строки заданной целочисленной матрицей размером n на m, в которой находится самая длинная серия. Серия - следующие друг за другом совпадающие по значению элементы.

Помогите дописать код пожалуйста. Никак не могу придумать как правильно написать алгоритм

Часть кода:

```
import random

m, n = map(int, input("Укажи длинну и количество строк матрицы: ").split())

matrix = [[random.randrange(0,10) for y in range(m)] for x in range(n)]

for i in range(n):
    print (matrix[i])
```

Comment: [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1177669/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be/1177682#1177682)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
    


      def check(m):
'''идет по списку, сравнивает соседние элементы, если следующий больше на 1, то увеличивает счетчик, если нет, то смотрит что лежит во втором счетчике и что в первом.
    Если второй счетчик больше, то просто обнуляет первый, если меньше, то присваивает новое значение второму счетчику и обнуляет первый. Возвращает всегда второй'''
        counter = 1
        counter2 = 1
        for i in range(len(m)-1):
        if m[i + 1] == m[i] + 1:
            counter += 1
        else:
            if counter >= counter2:
                counter2 = counter
                counter = 1
    if counter > counter2:
        counter2 = counter
    return counter2


m, n = map(int, input("Укажи длинну и количество строк матрицы: ").split())
matrix = [[random.randrange(0,10) for y in range(m)] for x in range(n)]

for i in range(n):
    print (matrix[i])
#применяем функцию ко всем строкам матрицы и ищем строку, с наибольшим значением
for i in range (n):
    maxLen = 0
    line = ''
    temp = check(matrix[i])
    if temp > maxLen:
        maxLen = i
print(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Дописал

```
list_k = []
for row in matrix :
    k_max = 0
    k = 1
    for i in range(m-1) :
        if row[i] == row[i+1] :
            k += 1
        else :
            k_max = max(k,k_max)
            k = 1
    list_k.append(k_max)

print(list_k.index(max(list_k))+1)
```